# onReceive from BroadcastReceiver is not called

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, action

I have a music application in which I am trying to add some action button on the notification bar.

I tried something like this:

```
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Intent onPreparedIntent=new Intent("MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED").putExtra("CURR_SONG",songposn);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(onPreparedIntent);
    Intent notintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(this);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent prevPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this,1,new Intent().setAction("PREVIOUS"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pausePendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this,2,new Intent().setAction("PAUSE"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent nextPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this,3,new Intent().setAction("NEXT"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);;
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.playicon)
            .addAction(R.drawable.back, "Previous", prevPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.playsmall, "Pause", pausePendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.forw, "Next", nextPendingIntent)
            .setTicker(songArtist)
            .setOngoing(true).setContentTitle(songTitle).setContentText(songArtist);

    Notification not=builder.build();
    startForeground(MusicService.NOTIFY_ID,not);

}
```

I declared a `NotificationReciever` class inside this service

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("here","here");
       String action=intent.getAction();
       if(action!=null){
           switch (action){
               case "PREVIOUS":{
                   playPrev();
                   break;
               }
               case "PAUSE":{
                   pausePlayer();
                   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MusicService.this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("STOP_THREAD"));
                   break;
               }
               case "NEXT":{
                   playNext();
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Structure looks something like this:

```
-MusicService extends Service 
    --NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
```

My manifest file contains reciever like this:

```
 <receiver  android:name=".MusicService$NotificationReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="PREVIOUS"/>
            <action android:name="PAUSE"/>
            <action android:name="NEXT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

When I run my music play, notification does come up with buttons but they don't seem to fire the `onReceive` function?

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

Followed hasif sayed answer and I seem to found an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService$NotificationReciev‌​er: java.lang.InstantiationException:java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor

Googling about it, I found that I have to use a static class or I have to register/unregister in the parent class.

So this is what I did:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new NotificationReciever(),new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new NotificationReciever(),new IntentFilter("PAUSE"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new NotificationReciever(),new IntentFilter("NEXT"));
    }
```

---

```
PendingIntent prevPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this,1,new Intent().setAction("PREVIOUS"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pausePendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this,2,new Intent().setAction("PAUSE"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent nextPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this,3,new Intent().setAction("NEXT"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now I don't get this above error but `onReceive` is not working again.

Comment: Good question and good answer at below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the reason why your broadcast reciever is not called when you click on **pause**,**previous** and **next** button is because ,you have set the pending intent to fire an **acitivity**,instead you have to set the pending intent to fire a **boradcast**

instead of this code snippet

```
PendingIntent nextPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this,3,new Intent().setAction("NEXT"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);;
```

you have to correct it like this

```
PendingIntent nextPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast
            (this,3,new Intent().setAction("NEXT"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);;
```

make corrections in all the three pending intent code which you have written

**UPDATE**

The reason why you still not receiving the broadcast in your Broadcast Receiver is because you are programitically registering  your Receiver as **LocalBroadCast**

When using with **PendingIntent**, **LocalBroadcast** will not receive the Broadcast

so please remove this Line

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new NotificationReciever(),new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new NotificationReciever(),new IntentFilter("PAUSE"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new NotificationReciever(),new IntentFilter("NEXT"));
```

Instead, you only have to **register** the **receiver** in the Manifest.xml file

**or** 
programitically you can register in code as

```
NotificationReciever mReciever = new NotificationReciever();

this.registerReceiver(
                mReciever,new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));
this.registerReceiver(
                mReciever,new IntentFilter("PAUSE"));
this.registerReceiver(
                mReciever,new IntentFilter("NEXT"));
```

but if you register this programitically, make sure you **unregister** it while service is getting destroyed. Otherwise you may LEAK the **BroadcastReceiver** Object

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService$NotificationReciever: java.lang.InstantiationException:java.lang.Class<com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService$NotificationReciever> has no zero argument constructor`

Got this error? any ideas?

Comment: @BOTJr. this issue is because, you have declared the BroadcastReciever as inner class on the service,when you declare this an inner class you cannot register that Reciever in the manifest.xml file

Comment: yes, i have to either use static class or i have to register/unregister my reciever in my parent class.I googled it. But i dont think that is working too

Comment: @BOTJr. ohh i have seen the edited Question, since you are using pendingIntent to send the Broadcast, in your application don't use LocalBroadcast , use normal Broadcast

Comment: thanks , it worked. please edit your code. It comtains too many typos.

Comment: @BOTJr. glad i was able to help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161450/discussion-between-botjr-and-hasif-seyd).

Comment: Very good! it save more time for me. When using pendingIntent.getbroadcast(), must use Intent().setAction("action_name_of_broadcast_in_manifest"). not use Intent(context, BroadcastName.class). Thanks!